# PL/SQL - accessing certain table cells from within a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am having trouble with the specifics of triggers, especially accessing different kinds of values from within the trigger and mutating table errors. (using PL/SQL Oracle 11g)

suppose I have the table fus:

```
|     |  A  |  B  |  id |
|-----------------|-----|
|row 1|  0  |  1  |  0  |
|row 2|  1  |  0  |  1  |
```

and I have the trigger ro:

```
create or replace trigger ro
after update of A on fus
when (new.A = 1 and old.A = 0)

declare
  da fus.B%type := :new.fus.B; --how do i do this correctly?
  cnt number(2) := 0;

begin
  select sum(A)
    into cnt
    from fus
    where B = da;

end;
```

and I have the statement:

```
update fus
  set A = 1
  where id = 0;
```

Obviously, I get en error where i declare 'da': bad bind variable; I just don't know **how to get the value of B where A has been updated.** Also I get a mutating table error where I tried to use a compound trigger but i still get the mutating table error when i run the update. Honestly, I do not understand why It's a mutating table; I just **want the trigger to fire after the entire update has completed.** I read how to solve this mutating table error on multiple posts on this site and other site, but I just can't seem to figure out how to solve this specific problem.

---

Here is my actual code:

**Trigger:**

```
-- 9-5 trig:
create or replace trigger bb_discount_trg
  for update of orderplaced on bb_basket
  when (new.orderplaced = 1 and old.orderplaced = 0) -- when orderplaced switches from 0 to 1
  compound trigger

    /* shared declarations */
    cnt number(2) := 0; -- just for readability
    newShopId bb_basket.idshopper%type := :new.bb_basket.idshopper; -----> /!\ FIX /!\

  after statement is
    begin
      /* count # of orders for this shopper */
      select sum(orderplaced)
        into cnt
        from bb_basket
        where idshopper = newShopId; -----> /!\ FIX /!\

      /* store # of orders */
      disc_pkg.pv_disc_num := cnt;

      /* if cnt is multiple of 5, then discount */
      if mod(disc_pkg.pv_disc_num, 5) = 0 then
        disc_pkg.pv_disc_txt := 'Y';
      else
        disc_pkg.pv_disc_txt := 'N';
      end if;
  end after statement;

end;
/
show errors
```

**Package:**

```
-- 9-5 pkg spec:
create or replace package disc_pkg is
  pv_disc_num number(2); -- stores number of orders
  pv_disc_txt varchar2(1); -- stores Y for discount, else no discount
end disc_pkg;
```

**Statement:**

```
update bb_basket
  set orderplaced = 1
  where idBasket = 13;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `:new.B` instead of `:new.fus.B` ?

Comment: You have another typo: `when (new.orderplaced = 1 and old.orderplaced = 0)` ( colons on host variables containing record value before/after are missing ).

Comment: @collapsar i made other triggers without the colon in front of the 'old' and 'new' in the 'when (...)' statement and they worked just fine.